# Is it possible to duplicate and modify a list in one step in R?

Tags: r, list

I find myself doing this a lot:

```
my_list <- list(a = list(b = "something"), c = 3, d = "a lot of other options") 

my_list_2 <- my_list
my_list_2$a$b <- "something_else"
my_list_2$c <- 5
```

I was wondering if there was a shorthand for this. Something like:

```
my_list_2 <- xxxxx(my_list, list(a = list(b = "something_else"), c = 5))
```

**Update**: My intended output is:

```
my_list # unchanged
my_list_2 # list(a = list(b = "something_else"), c = 5, d = "a lot of other options")
```

Comment: It is not clear what you wanted, Perhaps `rep(my_list_2,2)` or also check `?modifyList` for modifying

Comment: Like @akrun said, replace `xxxxx` with `modifyList` and you good to go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use `?within`:

```
within(my_list, {a$b = "something_else"; c = 5})
#$a
#$a$b
#[1] "something_else"
#
#
#$c
#[1] 5
#
#$d
#[1] "a lot of other options"
```

Of course the duplication is possible in the same step by assigning the result to a new object, e.g.

```
my_list2 <- within(my_list, {a$b = "something_else"; c = 5})
```

Comment: Thanks! This is great

Answer (score 4):

[modifyList](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/modifyList.html) is exactly of the form that the question shows for xxxx:

```
new_list <- modifyList(my_list, list(a = list(b = "something_else"), c = 5))
```