# Combine or merge recursively two list in R

Tags: r, list

I had this two lists:

```
firstList <- list(a = list(a_1 = 1:5,
                           a_2 = 5:10),
                  b = 10,
                  c = list(c_1 = 10:20,
                           c_2 = 20:30))

secondList <- list(b = 9999,
                   c = list(c_2 = 500:505))
```

I wonder to find an elegant function (few lines of code, no loops) such:

```
thirdList <- awesomeFx(firstList, secondList)
```

Gives me:

```
$a
$a$a_1
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$a$a_2
[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10


$b
[1] 9999

$c
$c$c_1
 [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

$c$c_2
 [1] 500 501 502 503 504 505
```

In other words, a function (o some way) that recursively replace elements within two lists.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34267440/is-it-possible-to-duplicate-and-modify-a-list-in-one-step-in-r

Comment: @akrun yes, I hope that other people can find the both askings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
modifyList(firstList, secondList)

$a
$a$a_1
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$a$a_2
[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10


$b
[1] 9999

$c
$c$c_1
 [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

$c$c_2
[1] 500 501 502 503 504 505
```

Comment: Perfect! That's what I was looking for.